# Is it possible to set a JPanel's size when creating a new JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I was wondering if there is a way to change the size of a JPanel when creating one.

My code looks like this:

```
add(scoreArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(gameArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I used the JPanels to create a border, but I would like to make them thinner. I am new to swing and I was just wondering if you could change the size in the same statement or if I would have to make JPanel objects and set the size there?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
add(new JPanel(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 300));
}, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Edit: Really downvotes? Just asking a question, I dont see the need for a downvote. What a community.

Comment: First, I'd suggest using the `Border` API, [How to use borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), it's rather powerful.  You're generally looking for `setPreferredSize` (although I'd discourage using it), but you could either create a custom class or factory method to do it for you

Comment: This won't work, `new JPanel(){setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 300));}` but **this** will: `new JPanel(){{setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 300));}}` -- note the double curly braces. But having said that, the better solution is to do follow @MadProgrammer's advice.

Comment: *"I used the JPanels to create a border.. Is there a way to do something like this?"* Use an `EmptyBorder` - it is not only 'a way' but indeed the ***best way*** to create the effect.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes? I am new to this and just asking a question? Is there somewhere else I can go more accepting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set margin for `JPanel` (contaiter) using [`EmptyBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) class:

```
EmptyBorder margin = new EmptyBorder(top, left, bottom, right);
getContentPane().setBorder(border);
```

Proper way to setup prefered size is:

```
Dimension size = new Dimension(width, height);
JPanel panel;

add(panel = new JPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.setPreferredSize(size); 

add(panel = new JPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
panel.setPreferredSize(size); 

add(panel = new JPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.setPreferredSize(size);
```